# reverse_landscape not getting triggered even if screenorientation is sensorlandscape

Tags: android, screen-orientation, landscape-portrait

I have added **screenorientation=sensorLandscape** to the manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".WorkoutActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
    </activity>
```

But the screen remains in landscape mode only and does not changes to reverse landscape on rotating the phone.

**NOTE:** Earlier I had set the screenOrientation to landscape and now changed to sensorLandscape.

**EDIT** Based on Vyacheslav's answer i tried this, but the orientation remains unchanged:

```
                    if ((rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90 &&  lastrotation == Surface.ROTATION_270)
                        || (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 && lastrotation == Surface.ROTATION_180)){
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                } else if((rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270 &&  lastrotation == Surface.ROTATION_90)
                        || (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180 && lastrotation == Surface.ROTATION_0)){
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
                }
```

In onConfigurationChanged, I called the method initOrientation()

Further when I tried the following code, the orientation doesn't stop rotating.

```
if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 ){
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                } else if(rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180){
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem.
I'm using OrientationEventListener

```
private void initOrientation() {
        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mLastRotation = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        myOrientationEventListener
        = new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI){
         @Override
         public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
//         O.Log.d(TAG, "ORIENTATION: " + orientation);
         Display display = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
         int rotation = display.getRotation();
         if (((rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90 && mLastRotation == Surface.ROTATION_270)
                 || (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270 && mLastRotation == Surface.ROTATION_90)
                 || (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 && mLastRotation == Surface.ROTATION_180)
                 || (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180 && mLastRotation == Surface.ROTATION_0))) {


             // do something

             mLastRotation = rotation;
         }
         }
         };

           if (myOrientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can DetectOrientation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            myOrientationEventListener.enable();
           }
           else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't DetectOrientation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          //  finish();
           }
    }
```

Try this (the code freezes UI rotation):

```
 if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 ){
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                    } else if(rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90){
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                    }
    else if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180 ){
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
                    } else if(rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270){
                        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
                    }
```

Comment: Hi Vyacheslav, can you please the edits that I made to the question based on your answer? Can you please guide me further? I want the orientation to remain in Landscape or reverse_landscape based on screen orientation.

Comment: @suku , Updated. Anyway, I'm really do not understand what UI implementation do you want to create.